# is it possible to have a checkbox control two button state

Tags: javascript, checkbox

i have a form with two buttons and a checkbox, i want when user checks the checkbox one of the button is enabled while the other button is disabled. So when the forms loads one will be enable by default and the other disabled, but after the checkbox has been checked the other becomes enabled while that which was enable by default become disabled..

i can actually do this for one button but i can do this for two button, please can someone with javascript skills help me out here thanks.

Comment: It's good practice to include the code for a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. Show what you've tried - that way we know that our answer will match what you need.

Comment: Just do the think you did for the one button again, but throw in a negation. Please show us the code you already have (even if it's not working).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with JQuery. Try the snippet below:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.checkbox_check').change(function() {
    var isChecked = $('.checkbox_check').is(':checked');
    $('#btn1').prop('disabled', !isChecked);
    $('#btn2').prop('disabled', isChecked);
  });
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id='btn1' disabled>Button 1</button>
<button type="button" id='btn2'>Button 2</button>
<input type="checkbox" class='checkbox_check' />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Update:**

Per the comment below, here's a Vanilla JS solution:

```js
function toggleDisabled() {
  var isChecked = document.getElementById("checkbox_check").checked;

  document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = !isChecked;
  document.getElementById('btn2').disabled = isChecked;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn1" disabled>Button 1</button>
<button type="button" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_check" onChange="toggleDisabled()" />
```

Comment: You could, but why would you? This is so much more bloated than plain DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Vanilla JS

```js
function fireChange() {
  const button1 = document.getElementById('test1');
  const button2 = document.getElementById('test2');
  button1.disabled = !button1.disabled;
  button2.disabled = !button2.disabled;
}
```

```html
<button disabled id="test1"> first button </button>
<button id="test2"> second button </button>
<input type="checkbox" onChange="fireChange()" />
```

Comment: Better don't just always toggle, it's easy to mess up and get one of the buttons out of sync and they never get back. Instead, derive the disabled status from the checked status of the checkbox.